# Workflow on a list where user can add but not edit items

Tags: workflow, permissions, custom-list

I don't get a lot of time on my organization's SP site and I don't have a way to install it at home. I'm wondering if something will work, or how. This is so I have all the information I need and don't waste valuable time trying to configure it.

I've got a list where users have permission to add but not edit items. I've got one workflow that changes the content type of the item after it has been created. I've got 2 other workflows that allow me to have a due date style system with daily e-mail alerting until the item is marked closed (http://www.attunix.com/about/blog/2013/october/17/sharepoint-2010-daily-reminder-loop/).

But I'm starting to wonder, if workflows run as the same permissions as the user and the user only has permissions to add, not edit, does that mean that the 3 workflows won't run unless I use an Impersonation Step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, they will fail if you don't use an impersonation step in the workflow if you are trying to do something the user doesn't have permission to do.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to post a new question for this but is it possible to create a workflow specific to each content type? One workflow will run when the item is created and it will change the item content type and the other workflow will then run on item changes?

Comment: Yes, you'd just need to set conditions on each one that checks the content type and exits if it doesn't match.